# String out of index with SQL developer

Tags: java, mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper, indexoutofboundsexception

I got below message from sql developer when I try to access.
I did just nothing special.

my connection info like below

- Connection name : z*sch***
- Username : root
- Password : it just numbers and characters(en)
- Connect Type : basic
- Role : default
- Host name : IP4 type address
- Port : 3306(MySQL)
- SID : z****_****

Sorry for '*', But I sure that I opened information that I can do. There is no long Strings, so I do not know why this program(SQLDeveloper) shows error message 'String out of range'. Give me the light! :D

> ```
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13113
>   at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:401)
>   at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:338)
>   at oracle.net.ns.Packet.extractData(Packet.java:439)
>   at oracle.net.ns.RefusePacket.<init>(RefusePacket.java:72)
>   at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:356)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1126)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:337)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:552)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:253)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:526)
>   at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.AbstractConnectionCreator.getConnection(AbstractConnectionCreator.java:153)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:195)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:67)
>   at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:321)
>   at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:254)
>   at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CADatabaseFactory.createConnectionImpl(CADatabaseFactory.java:60)
>   at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:534)
>   at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:208)
>   at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:607)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:172)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1064)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1045)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:115)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.AbstractConnectionNode.getConnection(AbstractConnectionNode.java:30)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter.getFactory(ConnectionFilter.java:94)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter$1.doWork(ConnectionFilter.java:119)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter$1.doWork(ConnectionFilter.java:104)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:515)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
> ```

Comment: You get this while you establish database connection?

Comment: `Port : 3306(MySQL)` It is supposed to be a straight number, isn't it?

Comment: Can you update your question with SQL Developer version along with the steps you took to reproduce the error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am sure you have solved this issue, but since I faced this issue and found the solution, I am posting it here so that it might help someone.

I got this error while trying to connect to mysql db via sql developer using the **oracle** db connection tab.
SOlution - Loaded the mysql-jdbc jar in sql developer(tools-preference-database-third party jdbc drivers) and when connecting to the sql developer database I selected the my sql tab (appears next to oracle tab in new connection wizard window).
Version of sqldev - 4.0.2.15

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will save someone's time. b

Answer (score 0):

I found one more solution for the subjected error.
The database I was trying to connect was located on other server. When I did telnet via putty to that linux/AIX server issue was resolved.