# String index out of range. Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I am trying to run a query using a Data Access Object within a Spring Application but I get a **String index out of range** error.

This is my DAO

```
public class UserDao {

   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
       this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
   }

   public int saveUser(User u){
    
     String query = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('"+u.getFirstName()+"','"+u.getLastName()+"','"
         +u.getEmail()+"','"+u.getCreatedAt()+"','"+u.getCreatedBy()+"','"+u.getUpdatedAt()+"','"+u.getUpdatedBy()+"')";
 
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query);
  }

}
```

This is the error
[image]

This is my Database table structure
[image]

Even if I substitute the getter methods with actual values I still get the error

Comment: Are you sure, that you use the correct driver implementation? You tagged question as 'mysql', but in stacktrace I see oracle driver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String out of index with SQL developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031648/string-out-of-index-with-sql-developer)

Comment: A bit of off-topic advice is to use `PreparedStatement` for building queries, avoid concatenating string yourself for SQL queries. This could lead to SQL Injection attacks. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong DRIVER implementation. I followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/  and everything works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using syntax like this:

```
String.format("INSERT INTO USERS(first_name, last_name, etc...) VALUES(%s, %s, etc...);
```

It will return a string dynamically created by `String.format()` method.

Because if you are not defined column names you have to maintain the order in values, and it could be bad because you are missing the id column.

P.S. %d - stands for numbers, %s - stands for strings